# How do I create a node count for each category term in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, taxonomy

I want to create a list of category terms (contained within a block), with each term to be followed by a count of the number of nodes with that term, e.g.:

```
Cats (5)
Dogs (4)
Elephants (2)
```

There are a number of modules that create whole lists like this dynamically, but I've found they all have drawbacks for my purposes. I literally just need something like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="mylink">Cats</a> (<?php ...some code... ?>)</li>
<li><a href="mylink">Dogs</a> (<?php ...some code... ?>)</li>
<li><a href="mylink">Elephants</a> (<?php ...some code... ?>)</li>
</ul>
```

I.e. I only need the count to be dynamic, not the whole list (this is OK because the terms  themselves will not change).
I've heard that the Drupal function `taxonomy_term_count_nodes()` may be useful, but I can't find any simple information regarding its implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What information do you want regarding its implementation? [The documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/taxonomy_term_count_nodes/6) seems pretty clear...

```
<?php print taxonomy_term_count_nodes($term_id); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I've done that a few times. IMO you're better off using Views to create a Node view that just lists Taxonomy terms, and then use the http://drupal.org/project/views_groupby module to put the number of nodes with that term beside the term. The example at the [views_groupby documentation](http://drupal.org/node/389230) tells you what you need to know.

Your custom module will obviously be a bit more flexible, but ultimately unnecessary given the above.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also not sure what information you are missing in the documentation - maybe an example helps. The following will create an ordered list of all terms within a vocabulary, with their node counts attached (untested, so there may be typos).

```
// Adjust this to the id of the vocabulary holding your terms
$vid = 1;
// Grab all terms in that vocabulary
$terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);
$items = array();
foreach ($terms as $term) {
  // Get the number of (published) nodes with that term
  $count = taxonomy_term_count_nodes($term->tid);
  // Assemble your link text
  $text = $term->name . ' (' . $count . ')';
  // Set this to the path you want to link to (default term views used here)
  $path = 'taxonomy/term/' . $term->tid;
  // Turn the above into a rendered link
  $link = l($text, $path);
  // Add to items
  $items[] = $link;
}
// Render array as an ordered list
$list = theme('item_list', $items, NULL, 'ol');

print $list;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Taxonomy_term_count_nodes](https://www.drupal.org/node/1084440) not exits in Drupal 7

Drupal 7 has another equivalent api to get taxonomy term's nodes. here is the api https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/funct...

It will return array value, we could count the array values with php

```
<?php 
  $data = taxonomy_select_nodes($tid);
  $count = count($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, you can actually do this with Views.  No coding or additional modules are required.  See [How To Use Views Aggregator to Create Taxonomy Term Count Block?](http://www.brightwebsitedesign.com/how-to-use-views-aggregator-to-create-taxonomy-term-count-block) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you get only 10 results with taxonomy_select_nodes that is because Pager is set to true by default in this function so you will need to do ti like this with 'FALSE':

```
$data = taxonomy_select_nodes($term_id, FALSE);
$count = count($data);
```